# iCloud Mail now defaults to conversation view?

Tags: icloud, windows, web-app

The web based app for iCloud Mail for Windows in Edge, Beta Nov 2022– is now  grouping emails by conversation. I can’t see how to turn that off. I work with straight chrono Inbox. I would like to switch back to chronological order for the Inbox.

Can that be done via the [iCloud web mail interface](https://www.iCloud.com/mail)?

Comment: Which beta are you talking about here?

Comment: iCloud Mail on a windows machine using Edge browser. www.iCloud.com/mail

Comment: Good that you gave details of how you access mail, but in this case the browser is irrelevant (same behaviour with Safari and Brave on macOS 13.1). There is no setting (in the web interface) to change viewing by conversation.

Comment: @bmike I don't think it is a bug, rather Apple's idea of great(?) functionality.